# Failed to resolve IP

Tags: c#, .net, networking, dns

Try as I might, I'm unable to resolve an address to IP. The code snippet is shown below. I keep getting the No such host is known exception, even though I could access google with my browser (The DNS server is almost certainly working). I'm however behind company's firewall.

```
try
{
   foreach (IPAddress address in Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.google.com"))
   {
      Console.WriteLine(address.ToString());
   }
}
catch (SocketException e)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Source : " + e.Source); // System
   Console.WriteLine("Message : " + e.Message); // No such host is known
}
```

Comment: I guess an "nslookup www.google.com" can't resolve the IP either?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your code.  Given that you can access www.google.com from a web browser the next most likely problem is that the web browser is using a proxy server.  The web browser is actually accessing www.google.com through the proxy server which is allowed through the firewall.  The simple application you wrote is not allowed through the firewall and is resulting in an exception.

You can verify this by looking at the proxy settings in Internet Explorer.

Tools -> Options -> Connections -> Lan Settings

There will be a proxy server group of settings.  If there is a value present, this is almost certainly your problem.

Comment: IP resolution is usually done within the firewall, however. He's not actually trying to connect to www.google.com on the code. My guess is that the proxy is doing the DNS lookup, and he just needs to reconfigure DNS locally.

Comment: I've seen it done both ways.  I've worked places where the firewall or other network security infrastructure will block DNS if it's not going through a proxy service of sorts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up the proxy:

here's a snippet that should set it up for all the following calls:

```
    protected void SetupProxy(string proxyUrl, string proxyLogin, string proxyPassword, string[] proxyBypass)
    {
        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUrl);
        proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(proxyLogin, proxyPassword);
        proxy.BypassList = proxyBypass;
        proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try through a browser, try pinging www.google.com (or some other host, of course) from the command line.

The ping itself may well not work, but it should show the IP address resolution first. If you get an error message like this:

```
    Ping request could not find host www.google.com.
    Please check the name and try again.
```

then it's likely that the proxy server is doing the DNS lookup for you when you're browsing, and your DNS server is either not working or your machine's network settings are incorrect.

Comment: This is exactly the case! Neither ping nor nslookup can resolve www.google.com in my network but it works perfectly while browsing. 
Moreover, numerous software (even git) can connect to remote hosts (like github) if I setup the proxy or if they pick it up from windows internet settings. Apparently proxy is resolving external addresses for me while dns is only for local names.
But what should poor .net dev do here? How can I use anything build on top of Sysetm.Net.Sockets?